# I need to slow down a video, including its audio

Tags: audio

I need to slow down a video, including its audio, while maintaining the audio pitch and minimizing any loss in audio quality. I'm working in Blender v. 3.3.1.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure audio pitching is even available